# Converting from v3 to v5 in d3 doesn't update the visualization but adds another one

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I tried to convert this d3 visualisation from version 3 to version 5 but instead of updating in the current visualization it keeps adding another visualization below. 
I added:

```
  d3.select(".node").selectAll("*").remove();
  d3.select(".link").selectAll("*").remove();
```

in order to remove the latest vis when updating but it's not working. Any idea why it isn't working?

here is the [link](https://codepen.io/gty996/pen/xxGzZZo) to the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `.remove()` directly with using the if statement.

```
...
function draw() {
  d3.select("#neuralNet svg").remove()
...
```

here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/mamounothman/pen/bGdKewE?editors=1010) for a working code.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help! If you happen to know, could you please also tell me why the hiddenlayerheight is not responding?

Comment: glad to help!, will check later once I have time